# Is there a reason why this form_tag element is always showing a syntax error?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backend

I am working on a `ruby on rails` application and have already made some of the core elements, like the login system. However, I am trying to make a logout button using the `'erb'` gem to load files and include them in other files, so all pages in the side have the form. However, no matter how I write the `form_tag` element, it raises a syntac error and I do not know why. I have looked on the internet and pasted the error code, but the solutions given still raise the same error. 
Any help?

Here is the code:
`app/controllers/session_controller.rb` (excerpt):

```rb
require 'erb'
...
  def home
    @page_title = 'Home'
    @topbarFile = File.read('file location') // not real
    ERB.new(@topbarFile, 0, "", "@topbar").result( binding ) // working! no errors
    if !session[:usrname].present?
      redirect_to '/login'
    end
    if session[:message].present?
      session.delete :message
    end
  end
  def delete
    if params[:commit].present?
      session.delete :usrname
      session.delete :id
      redirect_to '/login'
    end
  end
end
```

`app/file location` (not real location):

```
<div class = 'topbar'>
    <% sessionState = session[:usrname].present? ? [session[:usrname]] : [] %>
    <% logoutState = session[:usrname].present? ? [] : ['Log out'] %>
    <% sessionState.each do |username| %>
        <span class = 'username'><%= username %></span>
        <%= form_tag({controller: :session, action: :delete}, :class => '--logout-form') do %>
            <%= submit_tag 'Log out' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <% logoutState.each do |message| %>
        <a href = '/login'><% message %></a>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

`app/views/session/home.html.erb`:

```
<%= raw @topbar %> <!-- I have tried with raw(@topbar), still doesn't work -->
```

Here are the errors:

```
(erb):6: syntax error, unexpected ')' ...:class => '--logout-form') do ).to_s); @topbar.<< "\n ... ... ^ (erb):8: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')' ; end ; @topbar.<< "\n ".freeze ^~~ (erb):9: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')' ; end ; @topbar.<< "\n ".freeze ^~~ (erb):13: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
Rails.root: xxx

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
(erb):6: syntax error, unexpected ')'
(erb):8: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')'
(erb):9: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')'
(erb):13: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
(erb):6: syntax error, unexpected ')'
(erb):8: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')'
(erb):9: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')'
(erb):13: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
(erb):6: syntax error, unexpected ')'
(erb):8: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')'
(erb):9: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting ')'
(erb):13: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
app/controllers/session_controller.rb:65:in `home'
```

But there are no extra paretheses! I do not understand the problem! Why does it not work?

PS. why is the stack trace repeated so many times?

Comment: can you try use " instead of ' in class names

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: this :class => '--logout-form' write like this :class => "--logout-form"  around class names use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: There's no difference between using " or ' on that context

Answer (score 1):

Try `form_tag({controller: :session, action: :delete, class: '--logout-form'})`

Check the docs for the form_tag helper
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

It can take 2 option hashes.
The first option hash is one that's similar to the helper url_for, the second has extra params given in the doc.

What you did in your code was basically:

```
({controller: :session, action: :delete} #first hash of options, 
 :class => '--logout-form' #second hash of options with {} hash syntax, but without them.
)
```

That's why it's breaking I suppose.

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. Still staying unexpected ')'